# Finding longest time in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of phrases, like

```
"6 days, 7 months, 2 years"
```

and I need to go through the array to find the longest time and return that value. I've built something to insert into my application as a custom action but it crashes my application. It does not generate an error message.

```
bool booDayFound = false;
            bool booMonthFound = false;
            bool booYearFound = false;
            string DayPrognosisLength = null;
            string MonthPrognosisLength = null;
            string YearPrognosisLength = null;
            string strOutValue = null;
            int LongestDayLength = 0;
            int LongestMonthLength = 0;
            int LongestYearLength = 0;
            string[] arrDayLength = null;
            string[] arrMonthLength = null;
            string[] arrYearLength = null;

            string strPrognosis = Extracted_Prognosis;
            char charSeperator = ',';
            String[] arrPrognosis = strPrognosis.Split(charSeperator);

            foreach (var varPrognosis in arrPrognosis)

                if (varPrognosis.Contains("Day") || varPrognosis.Contains("Days") || varPrognosis.Contains("day") || varPrognosis.Contains("days"))
                {
                    booDayFound = true;
                    DayPrognosisLength = Regex.Replace(varPrognosis, "[^0-9]", "");
                    DayPrognosisLength = DayPrognosisLength + ",";
                    arrDayLength = DayPrognosisLength.Split(',');
                    LongestDayLength = arrDayLength.Max(c => int.Parse(c));
                }
                else
                {
                    booDayFound = false;
                    DayPrognosisLength = "";
                }

            foreach (var varPrognosis in arrPrognosis)
                if (varPrognosis.Contains("Months") || varPrognosis.Contains("Month") || varPrognosis.Contains("months") || varPrognosis.Contains("month"))
                {
                    booMonthFound = true;
                    MonthPrognosisLength = Regex.Replace(varPrognosis, "[^0-9]", "");
                    MonthPrognosisLength = MonthPrognosisLength + ",";
                    arrMonthLength = MonthPrognosisLength.Split(',');
                    LongestMonthLength = arrMonthLength.Max(c => int.Parse(c));
                }
                else
                {
                    booMonthFound = false;
                    MonthPrognosisLength = "";
                }

            foreach (var varPrognosis in arrPrognosis)
                if (varPrognosis.Contains("Year") || varPrognosis.Contains("Years")                || varPrognosis.Contains("year") || varPrognosis.Contains("years"))
                {
                    booYearFound = true;
                    YearPrognosisLength = Regex.Replace(varPrognosis, "[^0-9]", "");
                    YearPrognosisLength = YearPrognosisLength + ",";
                    arrYearLength = YearPrognosisLength.Split(',');
                    LongestYearLength = arrYearLength.Max(c => int.Parse(c));
                }
                else
                {
                    booYearFound = false;
                    YearPrognosisLength = "";
                }

            if (booYearFound == true)
            {
                strOutValue = "Year:" + LongestYearLength.ToString();
                localsmartobj.DCONavSetValue(ExtractedPrognosisLocation, strOutValue);
                AdmiralLog("Longest prognosis length is " + LongestYearLength.ToString() + "Years(s)");
            }
            else if (booMonthFound == true)
            {
                strOutValue = "Month:" + LongestMonthLength.ToString();
                localsmartobj.DCONavSetValue(ExtractedPrognosisLocation, strOutValue);
                AdmiralLog("Longest prognosis length is " + LongestMonthLength.ToString() + "Month(s)");
            }

            else if (booDayFound == true)
            {
                strOutValue = "Day:" + LongestDayLength.ToString();
                localsmartobj.DCONavSetValue(ExtractedPrognosisLocation, strOutValue);
                AdmiralLog("Longest prognosis length is " + LongestDayLength.ToString() + "Day(s)");
            }
            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AdmiralLog(ex.Message);

            return false;
        }
    }
```

I've trimmed some Datacap specific functions and I know that my code is not the cleanest but I would like to know what am I missing here?

Comment: For the purposes of calculations, would it suffice to assume 30 days in a month and 365 days in a year (even though 12 months/year * 30 days/month = 360 days/year)? Or are actual calendar dates available even though not shown in the question?

Comment: "Months" is a terrible unit of measurement if you are also using "Days". Just don't go there.

Answer (score 5):

First, we have to *come to terms*: let's assume that

```
  1 month ==  30 days
  1 year  == 365 days
```

Then we can implement `Duration` function: given a `string` return duration in *days*:

```
  Func<string, string, int> DurationTerm = (src, mask) => Regex
    .Matches(
         src, 
      $@"(?<number>[0-9]+)\s*{mask.TrimEnd('s', 'S')}s?",
         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value))
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Sum();

  //TODO: I've assumed 1 Month == 30 days, 1 Year == 365 days
  // Correct the logic if required
  Func<string, int> Duration = (src) => 
    DurationTerm(src, "day") + 
  // DurationTerm(src, "week") * 7 + //TODO: Add more terms if you want
    DurationTerm(src, "month") * 30 + 
    DurationTerm(src, "year") * 365;
```

Now we are ready to find out the longest time:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string[] arrPrognosis = ...

  int LongestDayLength = arrPrognosis
    .Max(item => Duration(item));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll see if I can implement it now!